# java.lang.NullPointerException while executing TestNG Class in @beforeMethod

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I Put the chrome.exe in the same project path but unable to execute it with this path: src\test\resources\Drivers\chromedriver.exe So I put thee path to be "D:\AutomationTask\automationTask\src\test\resources\Drivers\chromedriver.exe" and It worked fine yesterday.
Now I'm trying to run the project but I receive java.lang.NullPointerException in @Befre Class.

here is my code:

```
package testPackage;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import objectModels.AuthenticationPage;
import objectModels.RegistrationPage;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;

public class LoginTest {
WebDriver driver;
AuthenticationPage authentication;
RegistrationPage registration;

@Test(priority = 7)
public void loginWithCorrectEmailAndPassword() {
    authentication.EnterUserEmailForLogin("ayasalama@outlook.com");
    authentication.EnterUserPasswordForLogin("123456");
}

@Test(priority = 0)
public void LoginWithIncorrectEmail() {
    authentication.EnterUserEmailForLogin("ayasalama@outlook.eg");
    authentication.EnterUserPasswordForLogin("123456");
}

@Test(priority = 1)
public void LoginWithIncorrectPassword() {
    authentication.EnterUserEmailForLogin("ayasalama@outlook.com");
    authentication.EnterUserPasswordForLogin("12345");
}

@Test(priority = 2)
public void LoginWithEmptyEmailAndPassword() {
    authentication.EnterUserEmailForLogin("");
    authentication.EnterUserPasswordForLogin("");
}

@Test(priority = 3)
public void LoginWithEmptyEmail() {
    authentication.EnterUserEmailForLogin("");
    authentication.EnterUserPasswordForLogin("123456");
}

@Test(priority = 4)
public void LoginWithEmptyPassword() {
    authentication.EnterUserEmailForLogin("ayasalama@outlook.com");
    authentication.EnterUserPasswordForLogin("");
}

@Test(priority = 5)
public void LoginWithInvalidEmailFormat() {
    authentication.EnterUserEmailForLogin("ayasalama@gmail");
    authentication.EnterUserPasswordForLogin("123456");
}

@Test(priority = 6)
public void LoginWithInvalidPasswordLength() {
    authentication.EnterUserEmailForLogin("ayasalama@outlook.com");
    authentication.EnterUserPasswordForLogin("123");
}

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod() {
    authentication.NavigateToUrl();
}

@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "D:\\AutomationTask\\automationTask\\src\\test\\resources\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    authentication = new AuthenticationPage(driver);
    registration = new RegistrationPage(driver);
}

@AfterClass
public void afterClass() {
    driver.close();
}

}
```

and here is testNG trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at objectModels.AuthenticationPage.<init>(AuthenticationPage.java:26)
at testPackage.LoginTest.beforeClass(LoginTest.java:77)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:340)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:294)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:176)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:770)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:396)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: You are looking at the wrong class.  The stacktrace says that problem is in your `RegisterByEmailTest` class.

Comment: @StephenC May I copied another Trace but I have the same error in two classes, I've edited it now

Comment: @tgdavies UnfortunatelyNo

Comment: AuthenticationPage.java:26) error is at this line in authentication page class . add that class also

Comment: Now it's in your `AuthenticationPage` class which you haven't included.

Comment: 1) re your response to me: you need to correct that.  We cannot possibly diagnose an NPE from the wrong stacktrace.  2) re your response to tgdavies: You cannot possibly read, understand and try to the apply the advice in that Q&A in 4 minutes or less.  Hint: if we are going to help you, we are going to use the *methodology* explained in that Q&A.  So you may as well read the Q&A properly and apply the methodology yourself.

Comment: @StephenC the question is updated now

Comment: AuthenticationPage.java:26)  tells you whch class and which line , so check your authenticaation class and line 26

Comment: And add AuthenticationPage.java to your question, telling us which line is 26

Comment: @PDHide I found the error thank you

Comment: @tgdavies I found it thank you